# How to stop a process from System.Diagnostics.Process and get the statistics in the end

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mono, xamarin.android

I'm using this code but when i stop the process it not get the ping statistics :

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "ping";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-c " + count + " -i " + interval + " -s " + buffer + " -W " + timeout + " " + address;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

string readData = "";

DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5);
if (p.Start())
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(p.StandardOutput.BaseStream);

    while (scanner.HasNextLine)
    {
        readData =  scanner.NextLine().ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(readData.ToString());

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(readData) && !readData.StartsWith("---"))
        {
            Match M = Regex.Match(readData, @"^[\d]+ bytes from ([^:]+): [^ ]+ ttl=([\d]+) time=([^ ]+) ms");

            if (M != null && M.Success)
            {
                string IP = M.Groups[1].Value;
                string TTL = M.Groups[2].Value;
                string timeStr = M.Groups[3].Value;

                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Ping to {0} took {2} ms with a ttl of {1}", IP, TTL, timeStr));
                // Parsing the timeStr will work the same way as above
               if(dt > DateTime.Now)
               {
                   p.StandartInput.Write("\x3");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Match M1 = Regex.Match(readData, @"^rtt [^0-9]*([\d][^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/([^ ]+) ms$");

                if (M1 != null && M1.Success)
                {
                    float avgPingTime = 0;
                    float maxPingTime = 0;
                    float minPingTime = 0;

                    string minPingString = M1.Groups[1].Value;
                    string avgPingString = M1.Groups[2].Value;
                    string maxPingString = M1.Groups[3].Value;

                    // Now parse that value
                    float.TryParse(minPingString, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out minPingTime);
                    float.TryParse(avgPingString, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out avgPingTime);
                    float.TryParse(maxPingString, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out maxPingTime);

                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Min Time : {0} , AVG {2} ms, Max Time {1}", minPingTime, maxPingTime, avgPingTime));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Without using

```
if(dt > DateTime.Now)
{
     p.StandartInput.Write("\x3");
}
```

the result display like this :

```
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=1 ttl=46 time=13.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=2 ttl=46 time=13.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=3 ttl=46 time=13.9 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 3016ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 13.910/13.926/13.951/0.010 ms
```

but if I stop the `ping` using `p.StandartInput.Write("\x3");` it never goes to the `statistics` part it hangs at **sequence 1**  : `64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=1 ttl=46 time=13.9 ms` and dont continue reading , how to show the `statistics` after stoping the `ping` process ?

in other words my problem is when the user want to stop the `ping` it should display the `statistics` for the certain time that it was used to ping...

**UPDATE**

I have implemented `p.StandartInput.Write("/x3");` and it interrupts the ping process but it does not display the statistics and just hangs there.

Comment: Write a `Ctrl-C` to your std input stream, in hex it is `3`, so `Write("\x3")`

Comment: i have tried in `adb shell ping -c 3 8.8.8.8` with a CTRL+C but it just stop imediately , it don't show the statistics part ...

Comment: Just tried it and it produces the statistics lines... since you are testing via `adb`, actually shell in first `adb shell` and then run `ping` and then `Ctrl-C`, you are Ctrl-C/aborting the adb process not the ping process

Comment: It seems that if you call ```p.Exit()``` the ```StandardOutput``` gets locally closed too. Try defining the ```Exited``` before your loop. If your process gets killed this event will get raised. Try getting the latest output of the process (which is passed to the event as the ```sender```).

Comment: `adb shell`, then `ping 8.8.8.8` and then `Ctrl-C` to abort the `ping`, and the stats will be displayed, It also works from Process, as I use `ping` in a couple of my apps....

Comment: @HumpaLumpa007 , `adb shell` when im trying CTRL+C is not produces the statistics too when i stop the process (The terminal not closed in that way ) , why you think that in the code it will produce the statistics ?

Comment: @SushiHangover , yes you are right. Firstly `adb shell` than the ping request. Add it as answer how to implement in the code i will accept as solved.. thanks it works in this way

Comment: @SushiHangover , i have a last prob here , it stops the ping but not continuing reading the statistics.. i have updated my question too ...

Comment: Try to read StandardError property of the process just like StandardOutput.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808663/get-live-output-from-process

Answer (score 1):

If you are actually interested in the ping values, why not just use the ping class? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Because ping from Android System is better than Mono Framework , i have tried before and noticed that Round Trip Time is highter in MONO because of Sand Box .... It it not working as excepted ! And it have some bugs in IPStatus.TtlExpired .

Comment: If you are that concerned about the speed of the ping, why not write your own ICMP service?  Shelling out to perform that sort of function might be OK on a Linux system, but on a mobile/Xamarin, I'm not sure that is the correct answer to your problem.

Comment: why to write my own ICMP service ? I dont understand what you mean. The question is how to stop the process after it started via std exec.

Comment: I believe, stopping the ping command is a 'solution' to your problem, but your problem actually seems to be 'how to measure ping times between your device and some IP address'.   If measuring round trip times is actually your problem, then writing your own ICMP service (which is what PING uses) would solve your problem.

Comment: I think you dont understand well what i asked for. I get the time and everything else very good. The problem is not that !